# Flutter web 404 Not Found

Tags: flutter, .htaccess, web, web-config, flutter-web

Flutter Web after deploy in server 404 will appear I know flutter is single page application so we configure the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

but I use one static html file render in app so this method is not working ​and also I tried 404.html. No use please help me

Comment: What URL are you requesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
> ```

You have an erroneous literal `%` at the end of the *TestString* argument, so these *negated* conditions will always be successful, including when the request is rewritten to `/index.html`.

These conditions should be written:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

But note that for requests to the document root to be correctly rewritten you need to ensure that the `DirectoryIndex` is correctly set. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: This works for my hosting service. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I published my flutter web release on a windows server IIS and I got error on reload.
For the 404 error on the reload of my flutter page, I add a web.config file in the root of my publish beside index.html and I added this code inside.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules> 
          <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32917866)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!

Comment: @AnsonChen Great! happy to help.

Comment: After adding the web.config file, I encountered an error: Config Source: -1, indicating it couldn't read the configuration source. I resolved this issue by installing the IIS rewrite module from this link: iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the extra note. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Referring to MrWhite's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70570976/10148774) and [johannesmilke's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5o0oC2_J80&t=79s&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com)

Creating the file under './myApp/web/.htaccess'

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

seems to do the trick. And it seems it will also be included in the build by doing so.